# Mutual Information vs positive/negative correlations

Tags: information-theory, entropy

As we can read on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information), "Unlike correlation coefficients, such as the [product moment correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), mutual information contains information about all dependence—linear and nonlinear—and not just linear dependence as the correlation coefficient measures."

Anyway, Pearson's correlation coefficient can assume both positive and negative values. E.g. a positive correlation means that if one variable increases the other also increases, while A negative correlation works the other way: if one increases the other decreases.

Is it possible to infer a similar result also by observing the Mutual Information or another function based on information entropy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the mutual information is always positive, and it's insensitive to "directions" in the sense above. For example, $I(X;Y)=I(X;-Y)$.

As another example, the same paragraph of the Wikipedia shows that the mutual information of two jointly gaussian variabless is $-\frac12 \log(1- \rho^2)$, hence it's insensitive to the sign of the correlation factor.